# Importing resources with theme Liferay

Tags: resources, themes, liferay

I am trying to import some resources (journal articles, pages etc.) with my theme. I found solution : **Resources Importer**

> https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.2/development/-/ai/importing-resources-with-your-themes-liferay-portal-6-2-dev-guide-09-en

But I need to import .**lar** file with my theme. According with documentation, I put a .lar file in  /docroot/WEB-INF/src/resources-importer folder. After deploymnent of theme nothing happens... Lar file is not imported.

Maybe I am doing bad export. I am exporting my .lar from site template. Is it OK, or what can be problem? Please, any advice will be appreciated, because I spend a lot of days trying to solve this issue.

Again: I **cannot** use sitemap.json. I **have to** use only **.lar** file as only container of content, pages etc.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do not create lar file from site template. Export from a normal site. After that, deploy theme and you will find a new site template with the same theme name.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but in liferay 6.2 i cannot see any way how to export 'site'. It is possible to export site pages, web content, application display templates, site templates etc., but i cannot see solution how to export 'site'. :(

Comment: Export pages is the way to export site with pages and content. This is the only way.